# Lua - print the result of a function calculation

Tags: lua

I’m trying to print the results of a calculation carried out within a function

```
local celsiustemp = 37.5

local function toFahrenheit(c)
return c * 9 / 5 + 32
end

toFahrenheit(celsiustemp)

print("Temp in Celsius = '" .. toFahrenheit )
```

The resulting error is as follows .

> lua: convert c to f.lua:9: attempt to concatenate a function value
>   (local 'toFahrenheit') stack traceback:   convert c to f.lua:9: in main
>   chunk     [C]: in ?

I’m new to Lua, so I’m not sure what I’m missing ? Any help greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re close! Try:

```
local celsiustemp = 37.5

local function toFahrenheit(c)
    return c * 9 / 5 + 32
end

print("Temp in Fahrenheit = " .. toFahrenheit(celsiustemp))
```

The error message indicates that you were concatenating the function itself (can’t do that) instead of the result of the function, which is what you get when you actually call it (i.e. use `()`). In other words:

Can’t do:

```
print("Temp in Fahrenheit = " .. toFahrenheit)
```

But you can:

```
print("Temp in Fahrenheit = " .. toFahrenheit(celsiustemp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Each call of the function returns the value, so you must either store the function result into a variable or call the function within the print function itself:

```
local ftemp = toFahrenheit(celsiustemp)
print(celsiustemp .. " in fahrenheit: " .. ftemp)
```

Also you may want to learn more about function calls as this is generally the same method all programming languages use; it is just like a mathematical function that returns a value but you must store that value somewhere or you can use it directly as I did in the print function.